# Is there a way to display this WebGL intensive web site on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, webgl

I’d like to display Akamai’s [Real Time Attack Visualizations](https://globe.akamai.com/) WebGL-based website on a web browser running on my Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian OS.

That site is heavily-based on WebGL and whenever I try to load it, Chromium crashes.

Is there a way to get it to work? Or is the Raspberry Pi 3 simply not powerful enough to render a WebGL website like this?

Screenshot below of the actual website in action.

[image: Akamai’s Real Time Attack Visualizations]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to display this memory-intensive web site on a raspberry pi 3?

Doubtful.

That web site takes a while (and a lot of CPU/GPU load) to display on even a desktop system. It's not surprising at all that it fails to load on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently consensus is that site will never, ever work on a Raspberry pi, as comments mention *"A Rasperry Pi 3 has a Broadcom VideoCore IV GPU and while it’s an impressive GPU for such a small device, it’s not a workhorse for a site like since it shares memory with the CPU and to my knowledge the Raspberry Pi 3 only has 1GB of RAM that is shared between GPU and CPU. Won’t work with specs like that."*

But if you want to at least try anyway, there are options:

If ram usage is a problem, consider something like zram that could help a little with that issue.

If Chromium seems to be crashing, try not using Chromium. Use a different, hopefully better, web browser. Search your software repositories. Even try Firefox. Or some of these others currently in Debian stable:

- Epiphany (Tested & seems to work as good as Chromium, on Debian)
- Firefox-ESR (Tested & seems to work as good as Chromium, on Debian)
- Hv3
- surf
- NetSurf
- Dillo
- Conkeror
- [IceCat (GNUzilla)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuzilla/)
- QupZilla (*almost* works on Debian)

These may not work, but maybe worth a try:

- Xombrero
- Midori

luakit might even be a web browser too. There's quite a lot to choose from. It's difficult to say what will work for your particular hardware & OS, so find different browsers for your OS and start trying them. They're all free after all, so it's just a matter of install, run, test.

Comment: @JakeGould Lynx is gone, and a downvote for practical advice that's basically "try some different browsers, Chromium isn't the only game in town", seriously? You're saying nothing  will ever work, so just give up, don't even try?

Comment: Of your recommendations: Epiphany, QupZilla (now called "Falkon"), Midori, and Xombrero are all based on WebKit, and will probably perform similarly to Chrome. Icecat and Conkeror are substantially similar to Firefox. Hv3, surf, NetSurf, and Dillo are all minimal browsers and won't run a complex page like this one at all.

Comment: @duskwuff "probably perform similarly" sounds like "might not crash as bad", and then there's the Firefox family to try too, so at least there's some options that might have a chance. *(The attitude from others to not even spend a couple minutes and try a different browser is baffling, worst that will happen is just another crash like chromium, or nothing, same as now)*